# Merge org-clock entries

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

I wonder if there's an easy way to merge adjacent clock entries if they are within X minutes range?

for example

```
:LOGBOOK:  
CLOCK: [2015-06-28 Sun 11:54]--[2015-06-28 Sun 12:12] =>  0:18
CLOCK: [2015-05-18 Mon 11:07]--[2015-05-18 Mon 11:54] =>  0:47
:END:
```

would be simplified as

```
:LOGBOOK:  
CLOCK: [2015-05-18 Mon 11:07]--[2015-05-18 Mon 12:12] =>  01:05
:END:
```